# django and configparser, NoSectionError but the section is found

Tags: python, django, configparser, django-1.7

I have the following code in a django view.

```
full_path = BASE_DIR + '/' + full_path
print(full_path)
ksinput_path = full_path + '/KSINPUT'
print(ksinput_path)
import configparser
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
print(parser)
data = open(ksinput_path, 'r')
print(data)
parser.read_file(data)
print(parser.sections())
dhcp_network = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'DHCP_NETWORK')
ethernet_device = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'ETHERNET_DEVICE')
ip_address = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'IP_ADDRESS')
netmask = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'NETMASK')
gateway = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'GATEWAY')
hostname = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'HOSTNAME')
domain_name = parser.get('NETWORKING', 'DOMAIN_NAME')

if dhcp_network == 'No':
    NETWORK_LINE = "network --bootproto=static --device="+ethernet_device+" --ip="+ip_address+" --netmask="+netmask+" --gateway="+gateway+" --nameserver=10.19.21.40 --hostname="+hostname+"."+domain_name
else:
    NETWORK_LINE = "network --bootproto=dhcp --device="+ethernet_device

f = open(os.path.join(full_path, '/output'), 'w+')
f.write("Created iso with " + full_path +" and " + NETWORK_LINE + '\n')
f.write("This line intentionally left blank.")
f.close()
```

When I run this code, printing out the lines that matter, I get the following output on the console

```
/Users/jason/Desktop/kickstart_python/ks/myhostname.mydomain.com
/Users/jason/Desktop/kickstart_python/ks/myhostname.mydomain.com/KSINPUT
<configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x111cea828>
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/jason/Desktop/kickstart_python/ks/myhostname.mydomain.com/KSINPUT' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
[]
```

All of those paths are accurate. This is the contents of the KSINPUT file

```
[NETWORKING]
ETHERNET_DEVICE=eth0
HOSTNAME=myhostname
DOMAIN_NAME=mydomain.com
IP_ADDRESS=1.2.3.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=3.4.5.6
DHCP_NETWORK=No
```

When I run that from the django view, I get

```
Exception Type: NoSectionError
Exception Value:    No section: 'NETWORKING'
```

However, when I run this in the python shell of the virtual environment of the django app, it works:

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 13:10:29)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import configparser
>>> parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> data = open("/Users/jason/Desktop/kickstart_python/ks/myhostname.mydomain.com/KSINPUT", 'r')
>>> parser.read_file(data)
>>> parser.sections()
['NETWORKING']
>>>
```

I've been banging my head against this for a while and can't figure out what the problem is. Anyone see a glaring error?

Thanks much.

Comment: I'm no django expert (in fact, I've never used it ;-), but it looks like it replaces the builtin `open` function with `io.TextIOWrapper`.  What happens if you use `parser.read_string(data.read())`?

Comment: I get the same error. No Section.

Answer (score 0):

Any .ini file that the ConfigParser() looks up should sit directly under the Django project. Only then Django would be able to load. Therefore, the ini file name should be different for each of the application since they sit directly under the project.

Hope it helps someone. I really did a head break! :-)